# Error, "cout does not name a type"

Tags: c++

I am making a game on dev C++ and whenever I try to run my project it gives me this error saying, "cout does not name a type". I googled this but never could find an answer to fix my project. May any of you please help. Thank you.

Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
char button = 'a';

int main(button){





    std::cout<< "                                                                               \n";
    std::cout<< "   *********           ********         *          ****     ********           \n";
    std::cout<< "       *              *                * *        *     *   *                  \n";
    std::cout<< "       *             *                *   *       *      *  *                  \n";
    std::cout<< "       *             *               *     *      *     *   *****              \n";
    std::cout<< "       *             *              *********     * ****    *                  \n";
    std::cout<< "       *             *             *         *    * *       *                  \n";
    std::cout<< "       *              *           *           *   *   *     *                  \n";
    std::cout<< "   *********           ********  *             *  *     *   ********           \n";
    std::cout<< "                                                                               \n";
    std::cin>> button;

    if (button == n)
    {

        system("CLS");
        std::cout<< "    ***                                                \n";
        std::cout<< "   * ..*     ***                                       \n";
        std::cout<< "   * u *    * ..*     ***        .                     \n";
        std::cout<< "    ***     * u *    * ..*      ***                    \n";
        std::cout<< "     *       ***     * u *     * ..*                   \n";
        std::cout<< "    ***       *       ***      * u *                   \n";
        std::cout<< "   * * *     ***      ***       ***                    \n";
        std::cout<< "   * * * *   * * *   * * *     *****   O               \n";
        std::cout<< "   *   * * *   *  * * * * ** ** *** * /|\              \n";
        std::cout<< "   *    *    *   *   *   *     *   *   /\              \n";
    }else
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Invalid key enter n.";

}



}
```

Now that I have fixed my code thanks to you it gives me more errors,

```
30  16  C:\Users\Home\Documents\ICare.cpp   [Error] 'n' was not declared in this scope

42  15  C:\Users\Home\Documents\ICare.cpp   [Warning] unknown escape sequence: '\040'

43  15  C:\Users\Home\Documents\ICare.cpp   [Warning] unknown escape sequence: '\011'

47  3   C:\Users\Home\Documents\ICare.cpp   [Error] expected ';' before 'cout'

28      C:\Users\Home\Documents\Makefile.win    recipe for target 'ICare.o' failed
```

these are my  other errors.

Comment: I think you forgot to "enter code here" where it says to "enter code here".

Comment: `#include <iostream>` in top of your main and use `std::cout` instead of plain `cout`. If it this doesn't work please enter your code where it says `enter code here`.

Comment: Don't ask what it is for.

Comment: Don't ask what the project is for.

Comment: You need to read a book on C++ language basics. In C++ *statements belong inside functions*. You can't just write statements in the middle of the file, as in your code. You have to create a function (hint: `main`) and move your statements into that function.

Comment: Where is the main function??

Comment: I just put it in my code but I did not update it here yet. I will do it now

Comment: I am trying to make it so that when the user presses the n button it goes to the variable, button, and that is why I put the if statement there. But I might have done something wrong to it please let me know if you see anything that might fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you forgot to include iostream?

```
#include <iostream>
```

This has to go to the top of your code.

Also in order for cout to work without std:: in front of it you have to use the namespace:

```
using namespace std;
```

You cant write code outside a function. You need at least an entry point:

```
//includes and namespaced go here

int main()
{
    //enter your code here
}
```

I strongly suggest you work through [basic tutorials](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Hello%2C_World%21).

Your updated code has some errors:

```
system("CLS")
```

You forgot the ";" at the end

```
if (button == n)
```

You dont have a variable named "n". You probably meant to write:

```
    if (button == 'n')
```

Also in line 41 and 42, you have "\"s in your string. Those characters have a special meaning. Write another "\" before them to fix those errors.

The error is here:

```
int main(button){
```

It should be

```
int main(){
```

Ok i fixed your code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
char button = 'a';

int main() {
    cout << "                                                                               \n";
    cout << "   *********           ********         *          ****     ********           \n";
    cout << "       *              *                * *        *     *   *                  \n";
    cout << "       *             *                *   *       *      *  *                  \n";
    cout << "       *             *               *     *      *     *   *****              \n";
    cout << "       *             *              *********     * ****    *                  \n";
    cout << "       *             *             *         *    * *       *                  \n";
    cout << "       *              *           *           *   *   *     *                  \n";
    cout << "   *********           ********  *             *  *     *   ********           \n";
    cout << "                                                                               \n";
    cin >> button;

    if (button == 'n')
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "    ***                                                \n";
        cout << "   * ..*     ***                                       \n";
        cout << "   * u *    * ..*     ***        .                     \n";
        cout << "    ***     * u *    * ..*      ***                    \n";
        cout << "     *       ***     * u *     * ..*                   \n";
        cout << "    ***       *       ***      * u *                   \n";
        cout << "   * * *     ***      ***       ***                    \n";
        cout << "   * * * *   * * *   * * *     *****   O               \n";
        cout << "   *   * * *   *  * * * * ** ** *** * /|\\              \n";
        cout << "   *    *    *   *   *   *     *   *   /\\              \n";
    }
    else
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Invalid key enter n.";
    }
}
```

Comment: No I did include iostream

Comment: See the second part of my answer, did you write std::cout or do you have the using statement?

Comment: I have both. Mario Dekena

Comment: We need code to help you here. Click edit under your post. Go with the cursor to the end of the textbox. Make sure you are on a new line. Paste your code. Select you code with the cursor and then click the {} button in the toolbar at the top.

Comment: @zane I updated my answer accroding to your new code.

Comment: OK so I fixed everything that needed to be fixed but now it gives me this 1 error.

Comment: 13 18 C:\Users\Home\Documents\ICare.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Comment: You forgot a symbol somwhere. Check that you placed all your " ; " right. Also make sure The brackets ({}) are correct.

Comment: I checked it and I believe that I have everything placed correctly.

Comment: I will update my code.

Comment: Thank you so much.